# Path to resource files in C++ node

Tags: c++, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello fellow developers,

I have trouble determining the path to a folder containing resource files in a self written C++ catkin package. I am using the following macro in CMakeLists.txt to export the resource files (a couple of .xml files btw.):

```
install(DIRECTORY resources
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

This creates the following "resources"  folder:

```
home/ros/catkin_ws/install/share/opencv_ros_node/resources/
```

I need to access the resource files in my source code here:

```
string cascade_path = "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/opencv_ros_node/src/resources/haarcascade.xml";
haar_cascade.load( cascade_path );
```

Obviously, I do not want to use a hardcoded absolute path. But how can I determine the correct relative path to the resource folder during run time? (Ideally, this should also work if 'catkin_make install' has not been run explicitly)

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
Heiko

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73906/path-to-resource-files-in-c++-node/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-20**:
I guess you'd be OK if it's in PKG/resources as installed and not PKG/src/resources (or anywhere generically reachable). The src/ directory might not exist for installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the ros::package API:

[ros::package::getPath('PKG_NAME')](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/roslib/html/c++/namespaceros_1_1package.html#ae9470dd201aa4e66abb833e710d812a4) should give you the package path, where you can append your relative resource path to get a full path.

(under the assumption that this hasn't changed for catkin)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-08-20**:
Awesome, thanks for your quick help! The only thing is that I now have to hard code 'PKG_NAME'. Is there a command to determine the name of the package this command is executed in?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-20**:
I guess now it depends on what you want to do: If it's the package the source is in (or always the same), hardcoding would be OK. If that's not the case you can read it from a parameter or similar. Resources are usually given as package://MY_PKG/foo. If you need an open file: pkg: resource_retriever

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-20**:
The proposes API is still valid with catkin. It resolves the path of the package.xml file which is under INSTALL_PREFIX/share/PKGNAME. You should make sure that the relative path from there is the same as in the source checkout of your package. That ensures that it is found in both devel- and install space. For your example with the resources folder that is the case.

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-08-20**:
Thanks guys, I got it working :-)

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-02-07**:
Is there a way to retrieve the name of the package in which a node is contained? eg: `ros::package::getPath(ros::this_package::getName())`?

**Comment by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on 2019-05-07**:
Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-05-28**:
I keep getting `‘ros::package’ has not been declared` errors all the way.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-05-28**:
`#include <ros/package.h>`